# ¿Cómo cambiar el color a los estados activos de acordeón en Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Como puedo hacer para que cuando un acordeón este abierto la caja del titulo se pinte de color, en el ejemplo adjunto solo me pasa con el primero, ya que cuando abro el segundo debería ponerse de color el titulo y el primero quedar en blanco

```css
.panel {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.panel-group > .panel:first-child .panel-heading {
  border-radius: initial;
  
  color: #fff
}
.panel-group > .panel:first-child .panel-heading:active a{
    color: #fff
}
.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.panel-group > .panel:first-child .panel-heading a{
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #a80532;
}
.panel-heading {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532;
  border-radius: initial;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  color: #3c3b3b;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.panel-title a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 80px;
}
.panel-body h4{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black';
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.panel-body ul li{
    margin: 6px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.panel:last-child .panel-body {
  border-radius: initial;
}

.panel:last-child .panel-heading {
  border-radius: initial;
  transition: border-radius 0.3s linear 0.2s;
}

.panel:last-child .panel-heading.active {
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-radius linear 0s;
}

.panel-heading a:before {
  content: '\e146';
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.panel-heading.active a:before {
  content: ' ';
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}

#bs-collapse .panel-heading a:after {
  content: ' ';
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#bs-collapse .panel-heading.active a:after {
  content: '\e909';
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#accordion .panel-heading a:before {
    font-size: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f078";
    right: 14px;
    top: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#accordion .panel-heading.active a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<section class="pb-md-5">
  <div class="container pb-md-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-5 ">
        <h2 class="text-center d-block pb-4">
          PLAN DE ESTUDIOS
        </h2>
        <div class="panel-group wrap" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
               PRIMER AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <h4>1º Cuatrimestre</h4>
                    <ul class="nav d-block">
                      <li class="nav-item">• El Negocio Bancario</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Introducción a la Administración</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Derecho Comercial</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Contabilidad I</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <h4>2º Cuatrimestre</h4>
                    <ul class="nav d-block">
                      <li class="nav-item">• Administración</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Contabilidad II</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Matemática Financiera</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Derecho Laboral y de la Seguridad Social</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Mercados e Instituciones Financieras</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->

          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              SEGUNDO AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->

          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
               TERCER AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas cambiar un poco el css.  Tienes que aplicar el color de fondo al `h4` del titulo y restaurar el color a blanco en la clase `collapsed`.  Te dejo el ejemplo.

```css
.panel {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.panel-heading { padding: 0 }
.panel-heading h4 { background-color: #a80532; }
.panel-heading .panel-title a { padding: 10px 15px; color: #fff;}

.panel-heading .panel-title .collapsed { background: #fff; color: #3c3b3b;}

.panel-heading {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532;
  border-radius: initial;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  color: #3c3b3b;
  border-left: 3px solid #a80532;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.panel-title a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 80px;
}
.panel-body h4{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black';
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.panel-body ul li{
    margin: 6px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.panel:last-child .panel-body {
  border-radius: initial;
}

.panel:last-child .panel-heading {
  border-radius: initial;
  transition: border-radius 0.3s linear 0.2s;
}

.panel:last-child .panel-heading.active {
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-radius linear 0s;
}

.panel-heading a:before {
  content: '\e146';
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.panel-heading.active a:before {
  content: ' ';
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}

#bs-collapse .panel-heading a:after {
  content: ' ';
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#bs-collapse .panel-heading.active a:after {
  content: '\e909';
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#accordion .panel-heading a:before {
    font-size: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f078";
    right: 14px;
    top: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#accordion .panel-heading.active a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<section class="pb-md-5">
  <div class="container pb-md-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-5 ">
        <h2 class="text-center d-block pb-4">
          PLAN DE ESTUDIOS
        </h2>
        <div class="panel-group wrap" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
               PRIMER AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <h4>1º Cuatrimestre</h4>
                    <ul class="nav d-block">
                      <li class="nav-item">• El Negocio Bancario</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Introducción a la Administración</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Derecho Comercial</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Contabilidad I</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <h4>2º Cuatrimestre</h4>
                    <ul class="nav d-block">
                      <li class="nav-item">• Administración</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Contabilidad II</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Matemática Financiera</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Derecho Laboral y de la Seguridad Social</li>
                      <li class="nav-item">• Mercados e Instituciones Financieras</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->

          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              SEGUNDO AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->

          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
               TERCER AÑO
             </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ahh bien alan y te hago una consulta para que el a ref del titulo quede activo como hago? osea que cuando este pintado quede de color blanco, porque al parecer hereda un estilo general que es el gris

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  Simplemente tienes que ser mas especifico con tus reglas `css`.

Comment: Buenísimo! muchas gracias Alan